# Detecting a screen's width with Javascript

Tags: javascript, width, screen

```
if(screen.availWidth > 850){
    //Do this
} else {
    //Do this   
}
```

This is what I have right now. My issue right now is if someone was to zoom in to the page, I want the width to change as it will affect how the page is displayed.

Comment: If I zoom into a page I bloody well expect the layout of the items to stay the same. This will annoy users.

Comment: @millimoose On Facebook/Google+ for example, the chat sidebar gets removed or minimized if you don't have enough space. That's what I meant by affecting how the page is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't you be more worried about someone resizing their browser window? Not everyone keeps their browsers maximized.

To do this:

```
if( (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) > 850) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do other thing
}
```

I'm fairly sure this takes the zoom into account, but I've never tested that.

Comment: It does, thank you. I have to wait 6 mins before accepting though, -.-

Answer (score 1):

Bind an event handler to the [window.onresize event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp):

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (screen.availWidth > 850) { ... }
};
```

If you use jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 850) { ... }
});
```

Besides, if you want to create a responsive design, consider using [CSS media queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/). This automatically adapts the page if the user zooms or resizes the browser window and also works if the user has JavaScript deactivated.

```
/* CSS */
@media (min-width: 850px) {
    /* style */
}
```